# How to select elements from array field in dc.js / crossfilter / d3 and use each of them as separate data point for chart?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

For example, JSON element, where the "categories" field is an array:

```
{"city": "San Francisco, CA", "business_id": "15", "name": "Parastructure", "date":  "2014", "founder_education": "Stanford", "categories": ["Big Data", "Big Data Analytics", "Data Visualization", "Enterprise Software"], "Amount": "500000000"}
```

Using dc.js, how would I go about selecting each element in the array and adding it to the chart visualization?

```
var categories = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
     return d.categories; // this wouldn't work
```

});

```
var categoriesGroup = categories.group();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to tell crossfilter to treat elements of array as separate records instead of treating whole array as single key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524627/is-there-a-way-to-tell-crossfilter-to-treat-elements-of-array-as-separate-record)

Comment: That thread didn't really answer my question in a concise way

Comment: There isn't a concise answer.  You have to hack around it.  See also https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/535 and https://github.com/square/crossfilter/issues/5.  It would be great to create some utilities to make this easier.

Comment: You could also flatten your data so that each category gets its own row.

Comment: How would I go about flattening it?

Answer (score 0):

Crossfilter works best with a flat arrays of records.  If you don't like the idea of a reduce function creating maps, as suggested in the comments above, you can create a flat array out of your data basically by "multiplying out" the categories with the records.

So, something like this (using [underscores's clone function](http://underscorejs.org/#clone) to duplicate the records):

```
var product = [];
for(var r in records) {
    for(var i = 0; i < r.categories.length; ++i) {
        var r2 = _.clone(r);
        delete r2.categories;
        r2.category = r.categories[i];
        product.push(r2);
    }
}
```

(Warning: not tested.)  Now, where you used to have n categories in a record, you'll have n records, one for each category.  And you can reduce on `category` okay now.

...  Of course it might make your other calculations messy or not work ([some hints here](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/issues/5#issuecomment-4677666)), which is why I suggested the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524627/is-there-a-way-to-tell-crossfilter-to-treat-elements-of-array-as-separate-record?lq=1) first.  Unfortunately crossfilter was not designed for dealing with multi-valued fields.