# Using dimensions with arrays in dc.js/crossfilter

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Crossfilter supports dimensions with arrays since version 1.4.0-alpha.06 https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_with_arrays

Is it possible to exploit this functionality in dc.js?

I haven' found any examples yet... I am aware of the method described in [Is there a way to tell crossfilter to treat elements of array as separate records instead of treating whole array as single key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524627/is-there-a-way-to-tell-crossfilter-to-treat-elements-of-array-as-separate-record), but that works with earlier versions of crossfilter too (it does not make use of the new functionality).

Comment: Yes, it's possible. :) Would you care to contribute an example?

Comment: The cool thing about this is that you just use one of these array dimensions and it should work the same way as any other dimension in dc.js. I think...

Comment: P.S. I edited the version mentioned, as this functionality has not (and I assume will not) be introduced in the 1.3.x line.

Comment: Thanks, the crossfilter version I was testing was the issue... using 1.4.0 it is possible to get something going on with pies and rows. I'll post an answer with a working example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With help from comments above, I managed to get this working, very simple indeed if you use the right version of crossfilter (1.4.0). Works fine with `rowChart()` and `pieChart()`.

I made a an example bl.ock based on previous approaches:
http://bl.ocks.org/emiguevara/4bd152a8828f6b31270702d97dc0133d

Comment: Brilliant great for multipart survey questions. Thank you!

Comment: How to create bar chart  if the data set look like this 
{"key":"KEY-1", "state":"CA", "topics":["Technology","Science", "Automotive"],"medium":["paper", "web"], "date":new Date("10/02/2012"),"publication":[{at:new Date("10/05/2012"),publication_name:"MixMe"},{at:new Date("10/05/2013"),publication_name:"MC GRAW"},]}, {
"key":"KEY-2","state":"CA","topics":["Health"],"medium":["paper"],"date": new Date("10/05/2012"),"publication":[{at:new Date("10/05/2010"),publication_name:"Come On"},{at:new Date("10/05/2011"),publication_name:"MC GRAW"},]. Count on y-axis and publication name on x axis